# Windows 7 goes to sleep with wireless keyboard and mouse attached

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, wireless-keyboard

I installed Windows 7. Now I have the computer going to sleep every 2 minutes or so. It turned out that the wireless keyboard I am using is the problem. How do I fix this? Btw, both the keyboard and mouse from microsoft.

Comment: How did you conclude that the wireless keyboard is the problem? Have you tried increasing the sleep timeout in the power settings?

Comment: @Bobby I removed the keyboard and mouse, the problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your power management settings in the control panel and see if that has any issue. I haven't heard of the keyboard or mouse affecting this, but perhaps by adjusting these settings you might find some changes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the keyboard, I would guess the sleep button on the keyboard is stuck. But, to troubleshoot down further, remove the keyboard and see if the computer still falls asleep. If it does, w7pro's answer would be the correct one imho. If it doesn't, the sleep button may be stuck.

Comment: There is sleep button. See my comment above.

Comment: I would try looking either in the driver for the keyboard to see if you can turn the sleep button off, or sometimes there's a setting in your BIOS power management that disables the keyboard's ability to power off your computer. Or alternatively try going into your Power Configuration in windows and under the "When Standby Button is Pressed" choose "Do Nothing".